# pydantic: how to model AWS services and their resources?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, enums, pydantic

I would like to create a [pydantic](https://pydantic.dev/) model for a small subset of AWS services and their resources, so I can (among many other things) validate data loaded from configuration files, e.g.

```py
from yaml import safe_load

with open(<path to yaml conf file>) as stream:
  conf_dict = safe_load(stream)

conf = AWSServices(**conf_dict)
```

A sample `.yaml` configuration file might look like this:

```yaml
---
# name of the first service
EC2:
  # name of an EC2 resource (in plural)
  SubNets:
  
  # list of attribute sets for subnets to be configured
  # (not in scope of question)
  - subnet01_attr01: value01
    subnet01_attr02: value02
  - subnet02_attr01: value03
    subnet02_attr02: value04

  # name of a second EC2 resource
  VPCs:

  # (similar list as for Subnets)


# name of the second service
S3:
  # name of an S3 resource
  Buckets:

  # (similar list as for EC2 subnets and vpcs)
  

# name of the third service
DynamoDB:

  # name of a DynamoDB resource
  Tables:

  # (as above)
```

The `subnet01_attr01 ...`  bit is just for illustrative purposes and not relevant to the question.

So far, I've modeled only the top level, not using pydantic, but only a simple [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```py
from enum import Enum

class AWSServiceName(str, Enum):
    EC2      = 'EC2'
    S3       = 'S3'
    DynamoDB = 'DynamoDB'
```

which worked fairly well in my code to process all services in a somewhat elegant fashion.

**How would I model the second level, the resources ?**

I've tried adding more enums for the service resources:

```py
from enum import Enum

class EC2ResourcesName(str, Enum):
    SubNets = 'SubNets'
    VPCs    = 'VPCs'

class S3ResourcesName(str, Enum):
    Buckets = 'Buckets'

class DynamoDBResourcesName(str, Enum):
    Tables  = 'Tables'
```

and use them in the actual pydantic model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class AWSServices(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')
    service:   AWSServiceName
    resources:  ... ?!? ...
```

but I'm just completely confused how to continue here...

Is the `enum` approach reasonable ? Or should I better use a `set` ? (or a `frozenset` ?)